# Spring Boot MVC Thymeleaf Form Validation Problem Kotlin Class

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-validation

I had a problem with thymeleaf form and jakarta validation @Valid annotation and bindingResult - it didn't worked for me - I had always 0 errors

I spent a lot of time reading documentations, changing dependencies and more

Below my solution:

Answer (score 0):

finally I figured it out to modify my model class (properties) from

```
class Translation(
  @NotEmpty(message = "err")
  key: String,
  @NotEmpty(message = "err") 
  en: String
)
```

to

```
class Translation() {
  @NotEmpty(message = "err")
  key: String = ""
  @NotEmpty(message = "err") 
  en: String = ""
}
```